# What members of $\Bbb{Z}_2^{\times}$ don't have a multiplicative inverse?

Tags: group-theory, p-adic-number-theory

What members of $\Bbb{Z}_2^{\times}$ don't have a multiplicative inverse?

Is it just $0$?

My motivation is to better understand the multiplicative group.

Do all positive integers i.e. $1,5,7,9$?

What about negative ones such as $-5, -17, -25,-37$?

And fractions such as $\frac{125}{47}, \frac{211}{47}$

I ask not really knowing where to start I'm afraid.  Any answer should be pitched LOW.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what $\mathbb Z_2$ is supposed to mean. Is it the congruence classes mod 2, or something else?

Comment: @Ingix $\Bbb{Z}_2^{\times}$ is meant to denote the units of the completion of $\Bbb{Z}$ under the 2-adic metric.

Comment: If $\Bbb{Z}_2^{\times}$ denotes the group of units of the ring $\Bbb{Z}_2$ then _all_ its elements are invertible (by definition)…

Comment: Moreover, we have $\Bbb{Z}_2^{\times} = \Bbb Z_2 \setminus 2 \Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: @Watson ok thanks, so what is $0^{-1}$?

Comment: $0$ is never invertible… ! As I wrote, the units are the $2$-adic integers which are not divisible by $2$.

Comment: @Watson thank-you. So just to confirm I understand correctly, $\Bbb Z_2=(\{0\}\cup G)$ where $G$ is the multiplicative group of $\Bbb Z_2$? And pretty much the idea of $\Bbb Z_2$ is that its elements are all invertible.

Comment: No, that is practically the opposite of what @Watson just told you.

Comment: This is just a notational problem. I think you intended to ask which elements of ${\mathbb Z}_2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ have no multiplicative inverse.

Comment: @DerekHolt yes that's what I meant to ask.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft obviously what you wrote makes sense as it has 4 upvotes but to me where Watson wrote "all its elements are invertible" and I wrote "its elements are all invertible" it looks kinda the same and where he put "$0$ is never invertible" and I put $\Bbb Z_2=(\{0\}\cup G)$ where $G$ is the multiplicative group of $\Bbb Z_2$ we both seem to be saying $0$ is the only element missing from the multiplicative group. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You are missing essentially what Derek pointed out. Your original question asked about the units in the group of units, when you actually meant to ask for the non-zero units (and Watson told you what these were in a later comment).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft ah ok I've got it now. The element $x$ and its inverse need to fulfil $\lvert x\rvert_2=\lvert x^{-1}\rvert_2$ so they're only within $\Bbb Z_2^{\times}$ and none of $\Bbb Z_2\setminus\Bbb Z_2^{\times}$ has an inverse.

Comment: The last part there is true, but by definition. Putting the cross on the ring gives you *by definition* the invertible elements.

Comment: @RobertFrost I think it is a justified misunderstanding: Given a ring $R$, the notation $R^\times$ means ``all elements of $R$ which are invertible in $R$". It is true that $R^\times$ is contained in $R\setminus\{0\}$, but it is often much smaller. If $R$ happens to be a field, then $R^\times$ happens to be equal to $R\setminus\{0\}$, and this can lead to confusion when both rings and fields appear in the same discussion.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft ah ok. I was thinking of the cross as giving me those which satisfy $\lvert x\rvert_2=\lvert x^{-1}\rvert_2=1$, not realising the general principle of those being the invertible elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ring $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the closed unit ball (aka the completion of $\mathbb{Z}$) sitting inside $\mathbb{Q}_2$, or $$\mathbb{Z}_2=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}_2:|x|_2\leq 1\}.$$ Then $x\in\mathbb{Z}_2$ has an inverse $x^{-1}\in\mathbb{Z}_2$ if and only if both $|x|_2\leq 1$ and $|x|_2^{-1}=|x^{-1}|_2\leq 1$, which is the case if and only if $|x|_2=1$. Therefore $$\mathbb{Z}_2^\times=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}_2:|x|_2=1\}=\mathbb{Z}_2\setminus\{x\in\mathbb{Q}_2:|x|_2<1\}.$$ But the open unit ball we are removing above is exactly $$2\mathbb{Z}_2=\{2x\in\mathbb{Q}_2:|x|_2\leq 1\}=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}_2:|x|_2\leq 1/2\}=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}_2:|x|_2<1\}$$ because $|\cdot|_2$ can only take values in the set $$2^{\mathbb{Z}}\cup\{0\}=\{0\}\cup\{\dots,1/4,1/2,1,2,4,\dots\}.$$ That is, $\mathbb{Z}_2^\times=\mathbb{Z}_2\setminus 2\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the "unit circle" (aka, the difference between the closed and open unit balls) in $\mathbb{Q}_2$. From this it is not hard to see that $$\mathbb{Q}\cap\mathbb{Z}_2^\times=\{a/b\in\mathbb{Q}:2\nmid a\text{ and }2\nmid b\},$$ which contains all odd integers and fractions thereof (like the ones you mentioned).